# Proving Anti-Symmetry of divides relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

i broke up in a question.

The relation "divide" is Anti-Symmetric relation.

∀a,b ∈ Z : if a|b and a≠b, then b∤a.

Proof by contradiction, assuming that:

> (I) a|b
>
> (II) a≠b
>
> (III) b|a

How a|b, by def. of "divide":

> b = a.q , for q ∈ Z

developing a|b:

> b = a.q
> [For here, i dont know what i do]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why don't you go for direct proof. Try using the property that $a | b \Rightarrow \left| a \right| \leq \left| b \right|$. Also, use $a \leq \left| a \right|$.

Comment: Consider $a = 2$ and $b = -2$. Then, $2 | -2$ as $-2 = 2 \cdot \left( -1 \right)$. Also, $-2 | 2$ as $2 = -2 \cdot \left( -1 \right)$. Therefore, $a | b$ and $b | a$. However, $a \neq b$, i.e., $2 \neq -2$. So, it seems your claim is not correct. Or at least, you can conclude that it is not true for $\mathbb{Z}$. If you try using what I told above for $\mathbb{N}$, you will get the divides relation as anti - symmetric.

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you know a way to prove the way I asked the question? I'm very curious to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As A. Deshmukh notes, you're trying to prove something that's a bit to strong, because $1 \neq -1$ and $1 | -1$ and $-1 | 1$. However the only exceptions are of the form $a = -b$. To see this, suppose that $a \neq b$ and $a | b$ and $b | a$. Let $a = bc$ and $b = ad$. Then $a = adc$, so $dc = 1$. The only integer solutions of $dc = 1$ are $d = c = 1$ and $d = c = -1$. Since $a \neq b$, $d = c = 1$ is ruled out. Therefore $c = -1$, so $a = -b$. Q.E.D.